# Multiplying by a random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{Z^{m\times n}_q}$ be some matrix.

Let $B\in \mathbb{Z^{n\times k}_q}$ be a random (uniform) matrix.
Can I say that $C=AB$ is also random?

Comment: When you ask whether $C$ is random, do you mean to ask whether, like $B$, it is random with a uniform distribution?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that $B$ is an $n \times k$ matrix where each element is uniformly distributed? Are the elements independent of each other? What does the index $q$ stand for? Is there any information on the matrix $A$? If it were all-0s then of course $C$ wouldn't be random...

Comment: @A. Donda: It could be considered a random variable with a non-zero probability for only one outcome. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung, sure, but then what does "is random" mean? Everything's random. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be uniform. The probability that $C = 0$ is at least $P(A = 0) + P(B = 0)$, which is greater than the probability that a uniform $C$ is zero.

A sufficient condition for uniformity, however, is that $A$ be uniform among the *surjective* matrices - namely, for each $C$, the set $A^{-1} (C)$ has the same cardinality and therefore the same probability.

Comment: If $Rank(A)=r$ where $r\leq min\{m,n,k\}$, is it true that C is uniform over the set of matrices of order $m\times k$ with rank r?

Answer (score -1):

I think yes, it will be a random matrix of order (m x k)

Comment: Did you mean to format that in some way, like "$(m \times k)$"?