# Multiplication of two random matrices over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, finite-fields, random-matrices

Consider a matrix $\mathrm{X}$ sampled uniformly at random from the set of all rank $r$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q^{m \times n}$ and a matrix $\mathrm{Y}$ sampled uniformly at random from the set of all full rank matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q^{n \times n}$. Let $\mathrm{Z} = \mathrm{X}\mathrm{Y}$.

I am trying to prove something like the statement that $\mathrm{Z}$ is uniform over the set of all rank $r$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q^{m \times n}$.

Assume $m > n$ and $r \leq n$.

---

This old stackexchange [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260815/multiplying-by-a-random-matrix) says that this is indeed the case, but it does not explain how to reach the result. Is this a common result in random matrix theory, and if so, can someone provide a reference or a proof?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is relatively well-known and even true for the more general case, where $P(Y \text{ is invertible}) = 1$, i.e., $Y$ does not have to be uniform. We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $P(X=x)=p$ uniformly over all matrices $x$ of rank $r$.

A proof goes as follows. Let $z \in \mathbb{F}_q^{m\times n}$ be a matrix of rank $r$. Start with demarginalization to obtain
$$ P(Z=z)=\sum_{y} P(Y=y,Z=z) = \sum_{y} P(Z=z|Y=y)P(Y=y), $$
where the sum ranges over all invertible matrices $y$. Now, since $y$ is invertible, $z=xy$ if and only if $x=zy^{-1}$ and hence $P(Z=z|Y=y) = P(X=zy^{-1}|Y=y)$. Due to independence of $X$ and $Y$ we get $P(X=zy^{-1}|Y=y)=P(X=zy^{-1})=p$, as $zy^{-1}$ is a matrix of rank $r$. Consequently,
$$ P(Z=z) = 
\sum_{y} p P(Y=y) =p\sum_{y}  P(Y=y) = p, $$
which proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks! One question: your proof technique seems to not depend too much on the fact that the matrices come from a finite field. Is this proof technique then also valid when I change the distribution the entries come from?

Comment: @RandomMatrices Yes, I believe you can generalize this to matrices over rings, for example. The set of invertible square matrices will look differently then and you need to take care to choose the set $\mathcal{X}$ (over which $X$ is uniform) such that $XY \in \mathcal{X}$ (in your original case, rank does not change by multiplying with $Y$). The proof should remain basically the same. I also believe that the quite general Proposition from runway44 covers this case.

Answer (score 2):

We can generalize this to random variables and other group actions too:

**Proposition**. If $G$ is a finite group, $\Omega$ a finite set, $G\curvearrowright\Omega$ is a group action, $g$ is a $G$-valued random variable, and $\alpha$ a uniform $\Omega$-valued random variable, then $g\alpha$ is also a uniform $\Omega$-valued RV.

*Proof*. The probability $g\alpha$ equals a particular element $\omega\in\Omega$ is the sum of all $\rho_G(g)\rho(\alpha)$ for which $g\alpha=\omega$, where $\rho_G,\rho_\Omega$ are mass functions and $\rho_\Omega(\alpha)=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}$. How many times does each $\rho_G(g)$ appear in this sum? For each group element $g\in G$ there is exactly one $\alpha$ for which $g\alpha=\omega$, so basically we sum $\rho_G(g)\frac{1}{|\Omega|}$ once for each $g\in G$. But $\sum_{g\in G}\rho_G(g)=1$, so this winds up simply being $1/|\Omega|$.

This case has $G=\mathrm{GL}_n\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\Omega$ the set of rank-$r$ $\,m\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$, although this case uses a right group action instead of a left group action (but the logic is the same).

For fun, you can also try a more long-winded proof using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the fact conjugate elements have conjugate stabilizers, the fact "transporters" are cosets of stabilizers, etc.